# Calculate number of days between two dates?

Tags: time, go

How can I calculate the number of days between two dates?  In the code below I should get the number of hours, which means that I should only need to divide by 24.  However, the result I get is something like **-44929.000000**.  I'm only looking a day or two back so I would expect 24 or 48 hours.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeFormat := "2006-01-02"

    t, _ := time.Parse(timeFormat, "2014-12-28")
    fmt.Println(t)
    //  duration := time.Since(t)
    duration := time.Now().Sub(t)
    fmt.Printf("%f", duration.Hours())
}
```

Here's the executable Go code: http://play.golang.org/p/1MV6wnLVKh

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your program seems to work as intended. I'm getting 45.55 hours. Have you tried to run it locally?

Playground time is fixed, time.Now() will give you 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC always.

Comment: Ouch.  I used to know that.  I haven't used Go in a while.  Thanks.

Comment: This still gives the wrong result when daylight savings changes happen. a [Duration](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) only represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count. It cannot be directly used to calculate days without errors twice a year. Sigh.

Comment: @Rick-777 do you have any solution for solving the issue you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I worked on https://github.com/rickb777/date (forked from fxtlabs), which includes a `Sub` method. It uses the `time` api but works a bit harder to determine the dates of the two time instants before subtracting them.

Comment: `int64(math.Ceil(duration.Hours() / 24))` is what I use to find number of days between two dates, where `duration` is the difference between two dates.

Comment: @mikequentel but why Ceil ?

Comment: @AlexeyKhrenov in my case, wanted to know least integer value greater than or equal to amount calculated

Answer (score 14):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    date := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(date)

    format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    then,_ := time.Parse(format, "2007-09-18 11:58:06")
    fmt.Println(then)

    diff := date.Sub(then)

    //func Since(t Time) Duration
    //Since returns the time elapsed since t. 
    //It is shorthand for time.Now().Sub(t).

    fmt.Println(diff.Hours())// number of Hours
    fmt.Println(diff.Nanoseconds())// number of Nanoseconds
    fmt.Println(diff.Minutes())// number of Minutes
    fmt.Println(diff.Seconds())// number of Seconds

    fmt.Println(int(diff.Hours()/24))// number of days    

}
```

Here is the running code https://play.golang.org/p/Vbhh1cBKnh

Answer (score 3):

One caveat to be mindful of when using this technique of `timeOne.Sub(timeTwo).Hours() / 24` is that daylights savings can cause a day to contain only 23 hours, throwing this calculation off slightly.

Answer (score 2):

> the below code gives the list of all the days along with the number of days between the from date and to date:
>   you can click on the link for the code in 
>   Go PlayGround:https://play.golang.org/p/MBThBpTqjdz

```
to := time.Now()
from := to.AddDate(0, -1, 0)
fmt.Println("toDate", to)
fmt.Println("fromDate", from)
days := to.Sub(from) / (24 * time.Hour)
fmt.Println("days", int(days))
noofdays := int(days)

for i := 0; i <= noofdays; i++ {
    fmt.Println(from.AddDate(0, 0, i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happy programmer's day

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)    

func main() {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("UTC")
    now  := time.Now().In(loc)
    firstDate := time.Date(now.Year(), 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
    diff := now.Sub(firstDate)
    
    fmt.Printf("The difference between %s and today %s es %d days\n", now.String(), firstDate.String(),  int(diff.Hours()/24)+1)


    // Just a joke
    if ( int(diff.Hours()/24)+1 == 256 ) {
        fmt.Printf("¡Happy programmer's day!") 
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("On my computer it works...!?") 
    }
}
```